# Transform Array Value into Keys without Iteration

Tags: php, arrays

Here's the array:

```
array(
    array('code'=>'a', 'value'=>'Type A'),
    array('code'=>'b', 'value'=>'Type B'),
    array('code'=>'f', 'value'=>'Type F'),
)
```

How to change this so that it will be:

```
array(
    'a' => 'Type A',
    'b' => 'Type B',
    'f' => 'Type F',
)
```

using a PHP function only and without using loops?

Comment: `$arr = array_column($arr, "value", "code");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rizier123 is right. For PHP 5.5+:

```
$arr = array_column($arr, 'value', 'code');
```

For 5.3-5.4:

```
$arr = array_reduce($arr,function($out,$item){
    $out[$item['code']] = $item['value'];
    return $out;
});
```